# Amazon API Gateway APIs delete after I edit them

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-mobilehub

I have encountered a problem with AWS that is a bit frustrating.  When I create APIs through the AWS mobile hub, they auto-generate in AWS API Gateway.  However, when I go into API gateway and edit the API methods, then return to AWS Mobile Hub, it says that my APIs were locked and it gives me an option to unlock these APIs.  When I click unlock, it deletes all of my APIs from API gateway, even though I did not tell it to.  Does anyone know what could be causing this issue?  It concerns me that the APIs can be this fragile upon editing them, especially after I deploy me application.  Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't happen. I couldn't reproduce it, but we would be interested to investigate more. May be enable CloudTrail for your account to see which is triggering the deletion. However, deleteAPI has a low throttling limit and it shouldn't even be possible to delete several APIs immediately, even if you tried. Are you sure you are logged in the right API Gateway region where you had previously created APIs?